# Loading posts outside wordpress

Tags: posts, javascript, json, rest-api

I am trying to load posts outside WordPress on a static html page. So far I have a working example using React, http://v2.wp-api.org/ and https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios. This working example using react currently displays the posts properly but it is fragile and there is no fall back. Codepen example here, https://codepen.io/krogsgard/pen/NRBqPp/

I use this example to get my feed source using axios `axios.get(this.props.source)`. Then I use the examples react function to grab my latest three posts, including titles and images and load them into a static html page via

```
 render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "post-wrapper" },
        this.state.posts.map(function (post) {
            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                { key: post.link, className: "post" },
                React.createElement(
                    "h2",
                    { className: "post-title" },
                    React.createElement("a", {
                        href: post.link,
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: post.title.rendered }
                    })
                ),
                post.featured_media ? React.createElement(
                    "a",
                    { href: post.link },
                    React.createElement("img", { src: post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url })
                ) : null
            );
        })
    );
}
```

My blog's source wp json is

```
React.render(React.createElement(App, { source: 
"myBlogURL.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed&per_page=3" }), 
document.querySelector("#blog-post"));
```

Which correctly loads my latest 3 blog posts into the `<div id="blog-posts">`
I'm looking for a vanilla js way to do this with some fallback helpers. In case I forget to include the featured image to a post, the posts will not fail to load. Any ideas or examples would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: not sure what is actually the question here, and how is the react code relevant in any way. The way it sounds to me, you want to rewrite a react depended code into vanilla JS, but if that is the case how is it specific to wordpress?

Comment: I used the react example because it was the only working example I could find. I'm trying to find a simple example of using something like https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ and loading json through javascript. Looking for any *working* example or documentation

Comment: @Mills Finally what solution you have found? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want get posts in html file why so much trouble? just use rss feed of your wordpress website(or any website) in your html.